# Adding minutes to Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

I am currently attempting to add an amount of time to a calendar object. The input is coming from a time picker and the output goes to two strings.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new android.text.format.DateFormat();

    Calendar startTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //These two string will be like this: "08:15AM"
    int prevStartHour = Integer.parseInt(startTime.getText().subSequence(0, 2).toString());
    int prevStartMinute = Integer.parseInt(startTime.getText().subSequence(3, 5).toString());
    int prevEndHour = Integer.parseInt(endTime.getText().subSequence(0, 2).toString());
    int prevEndMinute = Integer.parseInt(endTime.getText().subSequence(3, 5).toString());

    //Get the difference in hours between two strings
    int hourChange = Math.abs(prevEndHour - prevStartHour);
    //Get the difference in minutes between two strings
    int minuteChange = Math.abs(prevEndMinute - prevStartMinute);

    //Set the date on the first label
    startTime.setText(dateFormat.format("hh:mmAA", startTimeCalendar).toString());
    //Add the difference in hours to the calendar
    startTimeCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourChange);
    //Add the difference in minutes to the calendar
    startTimeCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteChange);
    //Set the date on the second label
    endTime.setText(dateFormat.format("hh:mmAA", startTimeCalendar).toString());
```

Now this is the odd part... the hours add just fine and dandy while the minutes simply decide to stop working halfway through. Instead of adding the expected time (be it 15, 30 or 45min) it adds 30min every time.

Comment: Maybe your prevEndMinute and prevStartMinute are not the numbers you except for.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking the values of `hourChange` and `minuteChange`?

Comment: I'm sure that the difference between the two is correct. I've logged them and they flow normally (in differences of 15, 30 and 45min as I input them)

Comment: (looks to me like the difference between two int and not two strings)

Comment: What is `dateFormat`?  It's not a java.text.DateFormat, since that class has no two-argument format method.

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: I just added a little more body for an example. Essentially this is run every time a date picker is closed. It then simply roles the times on the strings so that the endTime is always a given amount ahead of the startTime.

Answer (score 0):

Change `hh:mmAA` to `hh:mmaa` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).